# SCP times out, but ssh connection works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy task1.zip from my desktop `/Users/myname/desktop` if I pwd, to a remote server. I'm connected to the remote server via ssh. I would like to copy the file to `/its/home/jt463/task1`(pwd path from the directory) on the remote server.

I have used the command below in the terminal when I'm connected to the server via ssh and tried it on the terminal on my machine:

```
scp Users/myname/desktop/task1.zip username@inf900179.inf.susx.ac.uk:its/home/username/task1
```

Error that I get when I try to use the terminal that's connected to the remote server:

```
Users/jonatantibarovsky/desktop/task1.zip: No such file or directory
```

Error that I get when I try to use my local terminal:

```
ssh: connect to host inf900179.inf.susx.ac.uk port 22: Operation timed out lost connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First scp to the intermediate server, using your credentials. Then, you should be able to scp from that server to the target.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.